# Spyder 4.0.1(python 3.7) cannot import class Ui_MainWindow from Qt designer autogenerated module

Tags: python, anaconda, pyqt5, spyder

I am still very new to python and trying to write a small program that contains a Main Window and a couple of pop-up dialog boxes. The older version of spyder (3.x.x, python 3.6.x) seems to work well with the code, but after I switched to the newest version of spyder 4.0.1(python 3.7) by installing the newest anaconda. It doesn't seem to import the main window UI class (Ui_MainWindow) that was automatically generated by the code generator and saved under the same folder where my logic python files and the rest of the automatically generated files are. Instead it looks for a different path under c:\Users\myusername

The files under my current working folders are

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hjh7.png)

My question is why the code doesn't have a problem import the autogenerated UI_Dialog saved in DatabaseLogin.py, but have a problem importing the Ui_Mainwindow saved in the same folder and named AnalysisDatabase.py

Any clue would be appreciated. Thank you.

The logic code started as the following

```
import sys
import struct

import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

from DatabaseLogin import Ui_Dialog # this line works
from AnalysisDatabase import Ui_MainWindow # problematic line
```

Error code:
ImportError: cannot import name 'Ui_MainWindow' from 'AnalysisDatabase' (C:\Users\myusername\AnalysisDatabase.py)

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer right after this was posted. It turned out there is a python file named exactly the same in the C:\Users/myusername. After deleting that file, python is again searching the current folder as a higher priority.